# $k$-Normal subsets of finite groups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group of order $n\geq 6$ and $k$ a fixed integer with $1\leq k\leq n$.
We define a $k$-property as follows:

$gA=Ag$ for every $g\in G$ and every $A\subseteq G$ with $|A|=k$;

- (1) For what values of $k$ does the $k$-property imply $G$ is abelian?

(For the values $k=1,2$ it is true, and for $k=n$ no)

- (2) Is it true for every $k$ with  $1\leq k\leq \frac{n}{2}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $1 < k < n$, the case $k = 1$ being trivial.

Fix two elements $a, g \in G$. The set $G \setminus \{ a \}$ has $n - 1 \ge k$ elements, so let $b_{1}, \dots, b_{k}$ be $k$ distinct elements of $G \setminus \{ a \}$.

Consider the $k$-element set $\{a, b_{1}, \dots b_{k-1} \}$. Since $g^{-1} A g = A$, we have either $g^{-1} a g = a$, or $g^{-1} a g = b_{i_{0}}$ for some $i_{0} < k$.

By the same argument applied to the $k$-element set $A' = A \cup \{ b_{k} \} \setminus \{ b_{i_{0}} \}$, which does not contain $b_{i_{0}}$, we find that indeed $g^{-1} a g = a$.

Since this holds for any $a, g \in G$, it follows that $G$ is abelian.

So the answer to your question (1) appears to be

> for all $k$ such that $1 \le k < n$.

Comment: Thanks Andreas! Is it also true if we add the condition $1\in A$ to the $k$- property?

Comment: I think it is safe to do so. In the proof, take $a \ne 1$ as you obviously may, and choose $b_{1} = 1$. And then note that $i_{0} \ne 1$, so $1 \in A \cap A'$.